# ResourceException: Class name is wrong or classpath is not set for MysqlDataSource

Tags: java, mysql, glassfish

currently I am following
[this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8349970/connecting-a-mysql-database-to-glassfish-classpath-is-not-set-or-classname-is-wr)

to solve

```
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: Class name is wrong or classpath is not set for : com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource
```

So, I added mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar to my glassfish installation as shown in the screenshot below:

[Glassfish installation directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMSeY.png)

After a restart of Glassfish I my .war still does not deploy with the same error message (stacktrace below)

```
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: Class name is wrong or classpath is not set for : com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource
    at com.sun.gjc.common.DataSourceObjectBuilder.getDataSourceObject(DataSourceObjectBuilder.java:278)
    at com.sun.gjc.common.DataSourceObjectBuilder.constructDataSourceObject(DataSourceObjectBuilder.java:117)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.getDataSource(ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.java:1383)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.DSManagedConnectionFactory.getDataSource(DSManagedConnectionFactory.java:163)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.DSManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(DSManagedConnectionFactory.java:102)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.allocator.LocalTxConnectorAllocator.createResource(LocalTxConnectorAllocator.java:87)
```

Does anyone know how to solve the problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by adding this dependency to my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.14</version>
        </dependency>
```

instead of placing the mysql-connector-java-8.0.14.jar
into /payara5/glassfish/domains/domain1/lib.

Comment: Great! Be sure to accept this as the correct Answer.